# How to save the sate of my Activity

Tags: android, savechanges, onresume, activity-lifecycle

I have an `EditText` followed by a list view under it.
So it works like this - when u type something in the edit text it shows items from the list which match the text above.
Anyway I need to save the state of list view. means if the user navigates away from this screen and comes back the list view should have the same state and the edit text should be filled with the same text. Hope u got it.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save your edit text input string on (over ride those methods)

```
protected void onPause()
```

And when user returns, you just bind your string to edit text view on

```
protected void onResume()
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Save your data in onPause(), and restore it in onResume() if needed.

Comment: Hi Stefan ! U know I am using these lines of code in my class -        @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
    super.onPause();
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
    super.onResume();
        
    }
It does work this way. I mean it gives me the desired result, but can u give me a little insight into it that how it works ?

Comment: When another activity launches, onPause() gets called, so you can store the data you want to retrieve when returning to your activity. When your activity is reactivated, onResume() gets called and you can restore your data if you need to. You have to be more specific with your question if this is not the answer your looking for.

Comment: ok, but what happens when we say super.onPause(); and super.onResume();  Besides when another activity is launched, whether our activity calls onPause() or onStop() ?

Comment: super.onPause() calls the onPause method on your parent class.